# Custodial account restrictions and limitations

Tags: investing

Does anyone know the limitations to a custodial brokerage account?

- Options
- Short selling
- ???

Comment: I guess the custodian? I suggest reading the account agreement.

Comment: Ok so I'm supposed to go find every account agreement for every broker?

Comment: You want us to do that for you?

Answer (score 2):

The limitations are likely to vary from broker to broker however, as a custodian you have a fiduciary duty to look after the best interests of the account owner that you are the custodian for.  I won't say that higher risk investments such as short selling are never appropriate, but I can't imagine a situation where they would be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

When I opened a custodial account for my newborn, some time ago, I had the choice to add a margin account to permit short selling, and options. I chose to add neither, and stuck to index ETFs keeping cost to a minimum.

That said, I'd ask your broker if these are available for their custodial accounts.

Comment: What broker did you use?

Comment: I happen to use Schwab, and no reason to leave them after 35 years. There are many to choose from.